# How to make a good look leaderBoard in javafx?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm writing a game in java using javafx,I have a Account class that has an array list of all accounts created while the game.

I want to make a leaderBoard that shows rankings,name and number of wins in a table style leaderBoard.

I searched and just found a TableView class but I want to make a more beautiful board,What do you recommend me to do?

this is the Image of what I have in my mind:
https://pin.it/54xfsdlvjxjfau

Comment: Try solve it adding  `css` to you `view`.

Comment: @kozmo Could you please explain your idea more specific?

Comment: `ListView` or `TableView`.